# Focusing on a different object in salah

Tags: salat

Salam, recently we bought a kitten and he was sleeping next to me whilst I read salah and for a brief moment I ended up looking at him but I didn’t move my head or chest, just looked at him for a second with my eye, is my salah invalidated because of this? Jazakallah Khair.

Answer (score 0):

Probably Not inshaALLAH. If this was all unintentional. It is same like we are focusing in our prayer on words what we are saying but our eyes are looking at Sajdah place... and mind is travelling around the world.

Prophet Muhammad ﷺ  Said.  Satan flows like blood in our body and it makes us forget our prayers and even for forget count of rakats.

It's mean this is satan which makes our mind defocus and moves our eyes (if we don't want to). So don't worry inshaALLAH ALLAH SWAT will forgive you... but if something happens so... try to perform a sajdah-Sahwoo.

May ALLAH guide us the Right path.

JazakALLAH

Comment: Ameen Jazakallah Khair for the answer